# How can i convert a hexadicimal string to hexadecimal byte?

Tags: java

In my application i am reading some data from table. Which is in string format. i  need to parse this data to byte.
Example:
suppose my string contain 0e
than i want to get 0e as byte value.
here `(byte) (Integer.parseInt("0e",16) & 0xff)`; will not work as it will  parse this value to integer .. Any help on this will be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the string always one byte long (two characters long)? Or do you need to create an array of bytes?

Comment: Yes i will create a arraylist of bytes which is later part. But first i want to get the same value i.e 0e from string.If string value is 0A than i want a byte value of 0A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though `Integer.parseInt("0e", 16) & 0xff` produces an `integer`, there's nothing preventing you from adding a cast:

```
byte b = (byte)(Integer.parseInt("0e",16) & 0xff);
```

You can use `String.Format` to verify that the conversion has worked properly:

```
String backToHex = String.format("%02x", b); // produces "0e"
```

Comment: if you see my code i have added cast but problem is that it will not give 0e as result which i want

Comment: @Rajesh, hexadecimal is just a way to represent numbers. `0e` is the same number as `14` in decimal, or `00001110` in binary. The `byte` data type stores binary only, not `0e` or `14` or any other numerical representation. I'm guessing you're expecting it to display `0e` when you try to print it, but that will require you to do additional formatting yourself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry i was little bit confused between hex and this byte value..Thanks for your  help.I  got the desired output.

Comment: @Rajesh If you wish to represent it in hexadecimal format, you can use `Integer.toHexString()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("0e", 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse byte by the following code:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("0e", 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert your string into a list of bytes.

```
public static List<Byte> parseStringBytes(String str)
{
    if (str.length() % 2 == 1)
        str = "0" + str; // otherwise 010 will parse as [1, 0] instead of [0, 1]                      

    // Split string by every second character
    String[] strBytes = str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
    List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>(strBytes.length);
    for (String s : strBytes) {
        bytes.add(Byte.parseByte(s, 16));
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Call like so:

```
System.out.println(parseStringBytes("05317B13"));
// >>> [5, 49, 123, 19]
```